# Handlebar.js template with dynamic form inputs using Underscore.js - Zendesk App

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, underscore.js, zendesk

I am trying to figure out how to submit and capture all form inputs in a dynamically created form on a Handlebar.js template using Underscore.js. This is occurring in a Zendesk custom app.

There is a .hdbs template and app.js file in the scenario.  The form loads and shows correctly.  The underscore.js function I am using does see the form input but only returns the very first input value/key.  It does not return the dynamically generated list of checkboxes.

.hdbs:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
<p>

</p>
  <form id="updateChecklist">
    {{listname}}:  &nbsp;&nbsp;{{complete}} / {{total}}
    <input type="hidden" name="listid" value="{{listid}}">
    <br/>
    <ul>
   {{#each tasks}}​
   <li class={{fontcolor}}>
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{this.id}}" id="{{this.id}}" {{ this.state }}> {{this.name}}
    </li>​
    {{/each}}

    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-large" id="update" type="button">Update Tasks</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
    events: {
       'click #update'           : 'updateSingleChecklist'
  },
```

...

```
updateSingleChecklist: function(event) {

     var serializedArray = this.$("#updateChecklist").serializeArray();

    var itemIdsArray = _.map(serializedArray, function(item, key){
       return {item, key};
    });

   console.log(JSON.stringify(itemIdsArray));
```

Current Incorrect Result: 
 [{"item":{"name":"listid","value":"56eafe771e9824def46a7d7d"},"key":0}]

What I am looking for is an array of the form inputs, including unchecked checkboxes.

I need:

```
[{"item":{"name":"listid","value":"56eafe771e9824def46a7d7d"},
{"name":"checkbox1","value":"56eafe771e9824def46a7d8c", "checked":"0"},
 {"name":"checkbox2","value":"24eafe771e9824def46a7c6d", "checked":"1"},
 {"name":"checkbox3","value":"71eafe771e9824def46a3r5g", "checked":"0"},
...
"key":0}]
```

Comment: {{this.state}} will be either "checked" or empty depending on some logic in the function sending data to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be lot simpler than I initially realized.  The solution to this issue for now is updated at https://jsfiddle.net/sde13q3m/3/ .

Essentially, the map array function with a simple evaluation in the return statement allowed me to collect all form fields and checkboxes for the controller.

```
var serialized = this.$('#myform input').map(function() {
return { name: this.name, id: this.id, value: this.checked ? "checked" :         "false" };
});
```